# rails- slimでのf.submitの文言指定

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim

Ruby on Railsで開発をしています。
createとupdateで使うformファイルでf.submitタグの文言はcreateでrenderするかupdateでrenderするかによって自動で変わってるんですが、そこを私が指定したいんです。
ですが、文言を指定するとcreateとでもupdateでも私が指定した文言に出てしまい困っています。
create時は’登録’、update時は’修正’と指定したいんですが何か方法があれば教えてください。
下記は自分のコードです。

```
= form_for @book do |f|
  div.form-group
    .field
      = f.label :番号
      = f.text_field :BookNum, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter...'
        .
        .
        .


  div.box-footer
      .actions
      = f.submit 'create book', class: 'btn btn-info pull-right'
```

Answer (score 3):

i18nの仕組みにのっかって、config/locales/ja.ymlにbookモデル用のhelpers.submitの設定を追加するとよいと思います。
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-submit

```
= form_for @book do |f|
  div.form-group
    .field
      = f.label :番号
      = f.text_field :BookNum, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter...'
        .
        .
        .


  div.box-footer
      .actions
      = f.submit class: 'btn btn-info pull-right'
```

config/locales/ja.yml

```
ja:
  helpers:
    submit:
      book:
        create: "登録"
        update: "修正"
```

Answer (score -2):

私は、controllerにsubmit用の変数を用意して切り替えています。

app/views/books_controller.rb

```
  ...
  # GET /books/new
  def new
    @book = Book.new
    @submit = '登録'
  end

  # GET /books/1/edit
  def edit
    @submit = '修正'
  end
  ...
```

app/views/books/_form.html_slim

```
  ...
  .actions = f.submit @submit
  ...
```